# Grouping and Splitting CSV Files Through UNIX Command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu, terminal

I have a large CSV file. I want to split it into multiple CSV files through UNIX command. My master CSV file contains three columns: Date1, Date2, and Count. I want to group by on Date1 and want Date2 and Count information in separate CSV files. I have lots of entries in master.csv file. I also would like to create file names exactly mentioned in the example. Following is an example.

```
master.csv
Date1,Date2,Count 
10/5/2014,10/12/2014,340
10/5/2014,10/19/2014,316
10/5/2014,10/26/2014,278
10/12/2014,10/19/2014,219
10/12/2014,10/26/2014,182
..........................
..........................


file_10_5_2014.csv
10/12/2014,340
10/19/2014,316
10/26/2014,278

file_10_12_2014.csv
10/19/2014,219
10/26/2014,182
```

How can I do split the master file like example provided above?

Comment: Nice plan. Where is the problem?

Comment: How can I do split the master file like example provided above?

Comment: Give it a try, if it does not work, come back with the code and then people may help...

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
tail -n +2 | while IFS=, read d1 d2 c
do
  echo $d2,$c  > file_${d1//\//_}.csv
done
```

Comment: It will not work. I have edited the question. Please check it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to use python or UNIX commands? You tagged the question under python but have asked for a solution using UNIX commands.

Try this:

```
tail -n+2 master.csv | head -n 3 > file_10_5_2014.csv
tail -n+2 master.csv | tail -n 2 > file_10_12_2014.csv
```

where the `tail -n+2` skips the first line.

Comment: It will not work. I have edited the question. Please check it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I suggest changing the title of your post to reflect the update. It looks like you want to do a grouping operation, not just straightforward splitting.